# Открыть файл формата .hdf5

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте дорогие программисты,подскажите пожалуйста, как открыть и прочитать файл формата hdf5 на языке c#

Comment: Если не хотите использовать байндинги или портировать код, скажем, с Java, то можно просто перегнать данные в JSON и дальше уже его распарсить: https://github.com/HDFGroup/hdf5-json

Answer (score 0):

Существует библиотека для .NET называется HDF5DotNet

Создание:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HDF5DotNet;
namespace HDF5Test
{
    public class HDFTester
    {
        static int myFunction(H5GroupId id, string objectName, Object param)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The object name is {0}", objectName);
            Console.WriteLine("The object parameter is {0}", param);
            return 0;
        }

        public static void runTest()
        {
            try
            {
                // We will write and read an int array of this length.
                const int DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH = 12;

                // Rank is the number of dimensions of the data array.
                const int RANK = 1;

                // Create an HDF5 file.
                // The enumeration type H5F.CreateMode provides only the legal 
                // creation modes.  Missing H5Fcreate parameters are provided
                // with default values.
                H5FileId fileId = H5F.create("myCSharp.h5",
                    H5F.CreateMode.ACC_TRUNC);

                // Create a HDF5 group.  
                H5GroupId groupId = H5G.create(fileId, "/cSharpGroup");
                H5GroupId subGroup = H5G.create(groupId, "mySubGroup");

                // Demonstrate getObjectInfo
                ObjectInfo info = H5G.getObjectInfo(fileId, "/cSharpGroup", true);
                Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup header size is {0}", info.headerSize);
                Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup nlinks is {0}", info.nHardLinks);
                Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup fileno is {0} {1}",
                    info.fileNumber[0], info.fileNumber[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup objno is {0} {1}",
                    info.objectNumber[0], info.objectNumber[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup type is {0}", info.objectType);


                H5G.close(subGroup);

                // Prepare to create a data space for writing a 1-dimensional 
                // signed integer array.
                long[] dims = new long[RANK];
                dims[0] = DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH;

                // Put descending ramp data in an array so that we can
                // write it to the file.
                int[] dset_data = new int[DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH];
                for (int i = 0; i < DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
                    dset_data[i] = DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH - i;

                // Create a data space to accommodate our 1-dimensional array.
                // The resulting H5DataSpaceId will be used to create the 
                // data set.
                H5DataSpaceId spaceId = H5S.create_simple(RANK, dims);

                // Create a copy of a standard data type.  We will use the 
                // resulting H5DataTypeId to create the data set.  We could
                // have  used the HST.H5Type data directly in the call to 
                // H5D.create, but this demonstrates the use of H5T.copy 
                // and the use of a H5DataTypeId in H5D.create.
                H5DataTypeId typeId = H5T.copy(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT);

                // Find the size of the type
                int typeSize = H5T.getSize(typeId);
                Console.WriteLine("typeSize is {0}", typeSize);

                // Set the order to big endian
                H5T.setOrder(typeId, H5T.Order.BE);

                // Set the order to little endian
                H5T.setOrder(typeId, H5T.Order.LE);

                // Create the data set.
                H5DataSetId dataSetId = H5D.create(fileId, "/csharpExample",
                    typeId, spaceId);

                // Write the integer data to the data set.

                H5D.write(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT),
                    new H5Array<int>(dset_data));

                // If we were writing a single value it might look like this.
                //  int singleValue = 100;
                //  H5D.writeScalar(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT),
                //     ref singleValue);

                // Create an integer array to receive the read data.
                int[] readDataBack = new int[DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH];

                // Read the integer data back from the data set
                H5D.read(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT),
                    new H5Array<int>(readDataBack));

                // Echo the data
                for (int i = 0; i < DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(readDataBack[i]);
                }

                // Close all the open resources.
                H5D.close(dataSetId);

                // Reopen and close the data sets to show that we can.
                dataSetId = H5D.open(fileId, "/csharpExample");
                H5D.close(dataSetId);
                dataSetId = H5D.open(groupId, "/csharpExample");
                H5D.close(dataSetId);

                H5S.close(spaceId);
                H5T.close(typeId);
                H5G.close(groupId);

                //int x = 10;
                //H5T.enumInsert<int>(typeId, "myString", ref x);
                //H5G.close(groupId);
                H5GIterateCallback myDelegate;
                myDelegate = myFunction;
                int x = 9;
                int start = 0;
                int index = H5G.iterate(fileId, "/cSharpGroup",myDelegate, x, ref start);

                // Reopen the group id to show that we can.
                groupId = H5G.open(fileId, "/cSharpGroup");
                H5G.close(groupId);

                H5F.close(fileId);

                // Reopen and reclose the file.
                H5FileId openId = H5F.open("myCSharp.h5",
                    H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);
                H5F.close(openId);
            }
                // This catches all the HDF exception classes.  Because each call
                // generates unique exception, different exception can be handled
                // separately.  For example, to catch open errors we could have used
                // catch (H5FopenException openException).
            catch (HDFException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Processing complete!");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Открытие:

```cs
H5FileId file = H5F.open("Tabelle.h5", H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);
            H5GroupId root = H5G.open(file, "/");
            long cntRoot = H5G.getNumObjects(root);
            string[] elemRoot = new string[cntRoot];
            for (int i = 0; i < cntRoot; i++)
            {
                string obj_name = H5L.getNameByIndex(root, ".", H5IndexType.NAME, H5IterationOrder.NATIVE, i);
                H5ObjectInfo info = H5O.getInfoByIndex(file, ".", H5IndexType.NAME, H5IterationOrder.NATIVE, i);
                string type = info.objectType.ToString();
                string s = obj_name + " - " + type;
                elemRoot[i] = s;
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                if (info.objectType.Equals(H5ObjectType.GROUP))
                {
                    H5GroupId gr = H5G.open(root, obj_name);
                    long cntGroup = H5G.getNumObjects(gr);
                    string[] elemGroup = new string[cntGroup];
                    for (int j = 0; j < cntGroup; j++)
                    {
                        string obj_name1 = H5L.getNameByIndex(gr, ".", H5IndexType.NAME, H5IterationOrder.NATIVE, j);
                        H5ObjectInfo inf = H5O.getInfoByIndex(gr, ".", H5IndexType.NAME, H5IterationOrder.NATIVE, j);
                        string t = inf.objectType.ToString();
                        string s1 = obj_name1 + " - " + t;
                        elemGroup[j] = s1;
                        
                    }
                    foreach (string k in elemGroup)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("->" + k);
                    }
                }
            }
            H5G.close(root);
            H5F.close(file);
```